# email verification is not working in laravel 8. when a user is registered, email verification is not sent to user. email configuration is correct

Tags: php, laravel

Also it does not generate any error

```
Route::get('/verify-email', [EmailVerificationPromptController::class, '__invoke'])
            ->middleware('auth')
            ->name('verification.notice');

Route::get('/verify-email/{id}/{hash}', [VerifyEmailController::class, '__invoke'])
                ->middleware(['auth', 'signed', 'throttle:6,1'])
                ->name('verification.verify');

Route::post('/email/verification-notification', [EmailVerificationNotificationController::class, 'store'])
                ->middleware(['auth', 'throttle:6,1'])
                ->name('verification.send');
```

Comment: user model also implements MustVerifyEmail interface

Comment: Have you verified your mailer settings? What does `dd()` return if you dump the controller methods

Comment: you shoule provide you email configuration, is it in sync mode o is it being queued?

Comment: Yes it is in sync

Comment: how to find implementation of this function`$event->user->sendEmailVerificationNotification()`  inside user model i cant find its implementation

Comment: can you share with us mail configuration?
and try to send email from tinker and share with us the result.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.